# URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_csv
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
import seaborn as sns

url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JinkaChandanaJyothi2000/project-ch/master/T1.csv"
#names=['LV ActivePower (kW)','Wind Speed (m/s)','Theoretical_Power_Curve (KWh)','Wind Direction (°)']
data=pd.read_csv(url)
print(data)
```

**Error:**

```
URLError: urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: can you check the internet connectivity in your pc? you can run "ping raw.githubusercontent.com"

Comment: there is no problem with your code it's working fine